# NULL inserted while Persisting new Entity, Mapping table column to 2 tables. doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I need to map the same column to 2 differences tables (lets say normal and extended).

```
 /**
 * @var ItemValue
 *
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ItemValue")
 * @JoinColumn(name="id_value", referencedColumnName="id_value")
 */
private $value;

 /**
 * @var ItemValueExtended
 *
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ItemValueExtended")
 * @JoinColumn(name="id_value", referencedColumnName="id_value")
 */
private $valueExtended;

/**
 * @var string $isExtended
 *
 * @Column(name="is_extended", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $isExtended = 'YES';
```

I have no problem with joining data based on the isExtended attribute using DQL:

```
 "SELECT id,idv FROM ItemData id 
      JOIN id.value idv WHERE  id.isExtended='NO'";
```

and

```
 "SELECT id,idv FROM ItemData id 
      JOIN id.valueExtended idv WHERE  id.isExtended='YES'";
```

but when ever I want to persist a new object, NULL is inserted in id_value column ?!!

```
 $oValue = ItemValue();
 .
 .
 $oData = new ItemData();
 $oData->setValue($oValue);
 .
 .
 .
 $em->persist($oData);
 $em->flush();
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

From Doctrine2 documentation:

> In the case of bi-directional associations you have to update the
>   fields on both sides.

**One** possible solution would be:

```
$oData = new ItemData();
$oData->setValue($oValue);
$oValue->setData($oData);
```

but it's tedious. **Another** better one is set the cascade option on both sides of the one-to-one association:

@OneToOne(targetEntity="ItemValue"), cascade={"persist", "remove"})

This way your code will work. You can choose the appropriate cascade options looking at [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-associations.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the case where both the parent and child entity are new entities (neither have been persisted) a PrePersist lifecycle event on the parent can help:

```
/**
 * ....
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class ParentEntity {...

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function prePersist() {

    foreach($this->getChildEntities() as $childEntity) {
        $childEntity->setParent($this);
    }
}
```

-

```
class ChildEntity {
....
```

This will automatically create the child -> parent relationship upon saving the parent.
In many instances Doctrine will then be able to work out the rest at the SQL level.